# Where in the US can I purchase Turkish Coffee/Cafe Botz/Mud Coffee

Tags: coffee

When I visited Israel I became a big fan of something they called "cafe botz" or mud coffee. It tasted real good, and you sort of poured warm water over it, stirred and waited for all the coffee material to sediment, I gues that is why its called botz in herbrew. It was marketed in the shops as "Turkish Coffee". I havent been able to get it in the Unites States. Where can I get, preferably online, good quality of this Turkish coffe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping or sourcing, which is not really a culinary or cooking question.

Comment: Middle eastern store sell it in bricks. 100% Arabica with good strong flavor, and sludge to stand your spoon up in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping or sourcing, which is not really a culinary or cooking question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turkish coffee is simply a very, very fine grind - basically ground into a powder - prepared by boiling it and subsequently waiting for sedimentation, more or less as you describe in the question.

There is no particular *kind* of coffee you need for it - any will do.

Just buy whole coffee beans in any coffee shop or bulk food store and ask for a very fine (Turkish) grind.  Most burr grinders can handle this; as Michael says, you can also buy your own burr grinder or use a specialized Turkish grinder.  Either one will tend to run you around $100.

(Note that you probably *won't* be able to get the right grind with the majority of blade grinders.  They're just too imprecise.)

Commenter [Martha](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/1887/martha-f) also points out that many coffees marketed as Turkish coffee will also contain a certain amount of cardamom or cloves, which is [confirmed](http://mideastfood.about.com/od/drinkscoffeetea/r/Turkishcoffee.htm) [by](http://www.natashascafe.com/html/turkish.html) [several](http://coffeegeek.com/guides/turkishcoffee) [internet](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/423586) [sources](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ABW7GW). If you try it with pure coffee and it doesn't taste right, try adding a small amount.

Comment: Some varieties of Turkish-type coffee have cardamom ground up in them. (Iraqi coffee does, for example.) If the taste isn't right, that could be the missing element.

Comment: This answer is right, but you don't need a new grinder. A normal grinder used for longer time will produce both coarse and fine particles. Cook coffee and water together until it foams up, take away from heat, strain through a coarsish (tea) metal mesh strainer into cup. The coarse particles will remain in the strainer, the fine ones will fall through and form sediment. That's how the Turkish people I know prepare it.

Comment: Where I'm from (East Coast US), most supermarkets that sell whole-bean coffee have a grinder available in the store for complimentary use; if I'm not mistaken, "turkish" is an available setting on these.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers which point to getting very finely ground coffee, the method of preparation is critical.  I learned to prepare it from Armenian friends, so I tend to call it "Armenian coffee", but the technique remains identical.  They ground cardamom with the coffee and stored it in the freezer until ready for use.

The pot used to make the coffee has a handle and a pinched collar below the lip to facilitate pouring brewed coffee while leaving the grounds (which are muddy).  Mix one teaspoon of coffee and one teaspoon of sugar with each cup of cold, filtered water.  More coffee or sugar can be added, but compared to drip coffee one teaspoon of each is will be both sweeter and stronger than usual.  Put the pot on low heat (the lower the better unless you are in some sort of hurry) but don't let it reach a boil.  If it isn't even close to a boil after a few minutes, you can turn up the heat a bit.  (A gas stove greatly helps control the amount of heat.)

When the coffee has neared a boil take it off the heat and let the coffee settle.  A drop or two of cold water seems to help with that.  Some people reheat the coffee once or twice more, but if you let it reach boiling slowly that step seems unnecessary.  When the grounds have settled, carefully pour off the top layer of coffee into small espresso-style cups for each guest.  It's very difficult to preserve enough foam for each cup, but do your best and use a steady hand.  Enjoy!

All sorts of details can be changed: sugar and coffee ratios, boil or not boil, number of times the coffee is reheated, which spices to add, and so on.  The key seems to be infusing the coffee directly in the water and leaving the grounds on the bottom of the pot via careful pouring.  In order for the grounds to be fully waterlogged and sink to the bottom, the coffee must be ground as finely as possible.  Since that also maximizes the strength of the coffee, sugar and spices are added to balance the cup.  And since the result has many, strong flavors, it should be consumed slowly.  So the entire process is a consequence of the method of preparation more than anything else.

It bears noting that this style of coffee is best experienced with good friends around a table, eating some decadent treat and discussing politics, religion or philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure where you can buy the coffee preground, but you can buy a coffee grinder (like [this](http://www.sweetmarias.com/sweetmarias/grinders/manual-grinders/zassenhaus-175-m-turkish-mill.html) one) that will give you the right grind for Turkish coffee. Then you just need an Ibrik (here's [one](http://www.sweetmarias.com/sweetmarias/frothing-pitcher-12-oz-long-handle.html)) and you can make it at home. And finally, here's a [guide](http://coffeegeek.com/guides/turkishcoffee) to make it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many Turkish Stores in US that you can purchase Turkish coffee, try Tulumba.com if your area does not have a local Turkish store. They have Turkish coffee as well as the pot used to brew (called a cezve). Turkish coffee tastes very different than others and even if you grind regular coffee it is not even close to Turkish coffee in terms of the taste.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- [Greek coffee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_coffee#Greece) is basically an alias for Turkish coffee so you can try Greek restaurants and grocery stores.
- Middle eastern grocery stores in big cities (such as L.A., N.Y. and Paris) will carry ground coffee from Israel (Elite) or other countries for making "Bots" or Turkish coffee.
- There is even a small appliance for making Turkish coffee. See, for example, this [Turkish coffee blog](http://www.turkishcoffeeblog.com/2008/12/automatic-turkish-coffee-machine-photo.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simply find an Arabic stores near you like a middlle east grocery store they sell Turkish coffee the 16 oz around 8 dollars there is two kind one with cardamom and one without!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Mazzer Mini grinder when you're sufficiently prepared to Do It Right.

Comment: Does anyone know if this actually has anything to do with Turkish coffee, or if it's just some kind of bizarre spam?

Comment: Turns out the Mazzer (not Mazzi) Mini is an expensive Espresso Coffee Grinder.
See this link: 
 http://www.1stincoffee.com/mazzer-mini.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best Turkish coffee I found on amazon is Andalusia Turkish coffee , you can buy it directly from amazon with free fast shipping in the USA :

[https://www.amazon.com/Andalusia-Turkish-Coffee-cardamom-Product/dp/B01KEEC0JU/ref=sr_1_6_a_it?ie=UTF8&qid=1474321421&sr=8-6&keywords=ameed+coffee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KEEC0JU)

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago I tried similar coffee in Dubai called Hamwi cafe, and finally found it in USA, you can order it online from www.hamwi.us

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in Russian supermarkets. This is where I buy it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

The coffee culture in chains in America won't likely have it although Asian stores if you search for any or special cafes may offer it

Many Americans do not drink Turkish coffee nor Canadians or even Europeans as it is very strong and concentrated and thick and compared to a regular or other type in a cup and often needs sugar to stand up to it unlike other light medium and even smoother dark roasts which need only milk or cream if that and not even sugar so people tend to prefer it

Some Arabic coffees are good and interestingly adding a bit of salt to the coffee balances and brings out the flavour more than sugar does. Large enough towns have cafes and stores other than chains or if those bigger ones with more selections